# I have one image before it is selected, when I choose it should be changed to another image

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I have a radio button and an image when I select the image should I replace it with another image

```
function getAirlinesById(idAirlines) {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "POST",
                url: '{{route('get-baggage-airlines')}}',
                data:"airlines_id="+idAirlines,
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#baggageAirline").empty();
                    for(let i=0;i<response.length;i++){
                        let category = response[i].baggage.category;
                        switch(category) {
                            case 1:
                            category = "KG";
                            break;
                            case 2:
                            category = "PCS";
                            break;
                        };

                        $("#baggageAirline").append('<div class="col-3 list-baggage"><input type="radio" class="input-radio-costum" required onclick="getPrice('+response[i].price_in_SGD+')" onchange="changeBackground('+response[i].baggage.config_baggage_id+')" name="baggage" value="'+response[i].baggage.max_range+' '+category+'"><img src="{{asset("assets/image/baggage.png")}}" class="image-default" id="image-selected'+response[i].baggage.config_baggage_id+'"><p class="baggage-amount">'+response[i].baggage.max_range+' '+category+'</p><p class="text-center tcc">'+response[i].currency_symbol+' '+response[i].price_in_SGD+'</p></input></div>');

                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    alert('ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT');
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
```

I have tried it like this, but the image I chose is still there and all of them are selected, only one should be chosen because it uses the radio button

```
function changeBackground(idBaggage){
        $('#image-selected'+idBaggage).css({
            'background-image' : "url('assets/image/baggageblack.png')",
            'margin-top' : '-30px',
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example of your code? Use a jsfiddle or a snippet. It looks like you are setting the background whenever the state changes (checked or unchecked) and always to the same image. I think you want to just make a simple CSS class with the background set and select on when the radio button is checked. `input[name='baggage']:checked ~ img { background-image: url(...) }`

Comment: Why are you setting the `background-image` attribute of an `img` tag anyway? Wouldn't you want to use a `div` or change the `src` attribute?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to replace as a background image, then create two class

```
.default-image {
  background-image: url('/path');
  .change-image {
    background-image: url('/path') !important;
   }
}
```

Initially add only `.default-image` class to the element, when you select the image, do onclick event and add the `.change-image` class. `.change-image` class property will override your `.default-image` property image.

Comment: Avoid using `!important` whenever possible. This is a bandaid, not a solution.

Comment: Do you have any idea to override the existing css property in same element, without !important.

Comment: The only reason you should use `!important` is if you are overriding some code that you have no control over and can't change. But if you can change it, then you should. Remove the inline styles and use specificity and pseudo class selectors to your advantage. If you select on the exact states that you want and apply your styles as needed, The code becomes much easier to manage.

Comment: Also, your answer (which appears to be in SASS) suggests that when displaying the changed image the element will have both classes, which would make the second background images more specific and would override the first value without `!important`.